# How to check if a cell contains the value of another cell in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 columns in 2 different tables both containing the same reference number, but in different formats.

Example:

table1.reference1  |  table2.reference2
58575218           |  00000000000058575218

I need to show records with different values on those columns, but in the example above it's just the same value with a bunch of zeros so, if reference2 contains reference1, it should be considered as the same value.

I've tried to concatenate '%' with table1.reference1 to ignore all these zeros but it doesn't seems to work.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 
ON 
    table1.key1 = table2.key2
WHERE
    ('%' & table1.[reference1])<>table2.[reference2]);
```

For the example above, it shouldn't show any records but it actually does.

Comment: Are you sure these are number values or string types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access uses `*` instead of `%` to denote multiple characters:

```
where table2.[reference2] not like "*" & table1.[reference1]
```

Find more here: [Like Operator](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in MS Access would be:

```
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     table2 
     ON table1.key1 = table2.key2
WHERE table2.[reference2] NOT LIKE "*" & table1.[reference1]
```

Or:

```
WHERE INSTR(table2.[reference2], table1.[reference1]) = 0
```

Comment: As I've been told, `%` must be replaced by `*` in your first solution. The second one with the `INSTR` function works perfectly.

Comment: @ffSAM . . . Yes, that would be the right wildcard for MS Access.